# Get value from one field in python in MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to get the value of the field. I have this query:

```
latest_id = cur.execute("SELECT ID FROM INSIDE ORDER BY `INSIDE`.`ID` LIMIT 1");
```

But as a result I get the amount of rows (1 because of the LIMIT 1) How can I get the value of the field?

Comment: You are selecting the `ID` and you get the **value** of first `ID` - which is `1`. It's not the number of rows.

Comment: When I remove the LIMIT 1 I get the amount of rows, so I think that is not the problem...

Comment: I don't have a clue of python, but you probably need `cur.fetchone()`

Answer (score 0):

No, you're getting the value of the 'ID' column in the 'INSIDE' table, which happens to be 1.

Comment: What do I have to change?

Comment: I would like to have the value of the field.

Comment: Which field, you're getting the id field, because that's what your query specified.

Comment: I would like to have the field with the highest ID value.